# Maclaurin series and basis

Tags: linear-algebra, taylor-expansion

I know from a calculus course that all differentiable functions can decompose into some Maclaurin series, therefore can we say that $(1, x, x^2, \dots)$ forms a basis for the vector space that consists of all differentiable functions? Or need I specify that the functions are real-valued, or maybe something else, to make the above statement true?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The vector space of which $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots\}$ is a basis is the space of all *polynomial* functions from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R$, which is a strict subset of the space of all differeintiable functions from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R$. Besides, it is false that all differentiable functions have a Maclaurin series; for instance$$\begin{array}{ccc}\Bbb R&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}x^2&\text{ if }x\geqslant0\\-x^2&\text{ if }x<0\end{cases}\end{array}$$has no Maclaurin series. Even if you are dealing only with those functions $f$ which have a Maclaurin series, usually that series converges to $f(x)$ only in a neighborhood of $0$, rather than everywhere.

Comment: Thank you. Then can we say that the set {$sin(mx), cos(nx) | m, n ∈ R$} spans all differentiable functions mapping from R to R?

Comment: Certainly not! How would you express $x$ as a linear combination of functions from that set?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Hey José, I would like to know why exactly the set is not a basis for functions with a Mclaurin series expansion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mohamedshawky Because in Linear Algebra we deal only with *finite* linear combinations of vectors. And every linear combination of a finite number of elements of the set $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots\}$ is a polynomial function.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you. I apologize if I asked a lot of questions, but according to the book Linear Algebra done right, if I understand well, the functions with a Maclaurin series expansion form an infinite-dimensional vector space, because you need a linear combination of an infinite number of linearly independent vectors $x^j$, that span the space, to construct an element and they follow the rules of a vector space like commutativity, associativity, etc. So, I think infinite-dimensional vector spaces do exist in linear algebra, though not typically taught. What do you think? TIA.

Comment: @mohamedshawky *Of course* that there are infinite-dimensional vector spaces. I mentioned one of them: the space of all polynomial functions from $\Bbb R$ into itself. Nevertheless, in *every* vector space $V$ with a basis $\mathcal B$, every element of $V$ can be written as a linear combination of *finitely many* elements of $\mathcal B$. That's part of the definition of basis.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ok, now I understand. Thank you!